# Pose Estimation Using Associative Embedding technique

Tags: computer-vision, heatmap, openvino, pose-estimation, efficientnet

In  Pose Estimation Using Associative Embedding technique I still don't have clarity regarding How we can group the detected points from HeatMaps to Individual Human Poses using Associative Embeddings Layer. Is there any code that clearly gives Idea regarding this ? I'm Using EfficientHRNet approach for Pose Estimation.

Extracted KeyPoints from Heatmaps and need to group those points into individual poses using Embedding Layer Output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OpenVINO perspective, we could offer:

1. This model: [human-pose-estimation-0007](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/omz_models_model_human_pose_estimation_0007.html)
2. This IE demo: [Human Pose Estimation Python* Demo](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/omz_demos_human_pose_estimation_demo_python.html)

This model utilized the Associative Embedding technique.
However, if you want to build it from scratch, you'll need to design your own Deep Learning architecture, implement and train the neural network.

[This research paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/3294771.3294988) might give you some insight into things that you need to decide (eg batch, optimization algorithm, learning rate, etc).